# How can i install sun java to Fedora 8

Tags: linux, java, fedora

I want to install java on my Fedora 8 server but come to the step 9 that is mentioned in [this guide](http://fedorasolved.org/browser-solutions/java-i386)

but at step 10 when I enter this command:

```
ln -s /opt/jre1.6.0_18/plugin/i386/ns7/libjavaplugin_oji.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin_oji.so
```

it gives the following error:

```
ln -s /opt/jre1.6.0_18/plugin/i386/ns7/libjavaplugin_oji.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin_oji.so
ln: creating symbolic link `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin_oji.so': No such file or directory
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Your question belongs to superuser.com

Comment: This should probably be on superuser, but...have you tried creating that folder?

Comment: There is also the question - why do you need a Java browser plugin on a server :-)

Comment: i don't want java browser.. i want to install java on server

Comment: Then you can safely ignore this problem - this step of the installation is to get the Java plugin working in Firefox...

Answer (score 1):

You must use rpm package of JDK go to [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp) page and select rpm base package and rpm installer in fedora install JDK completely